# Showing ads simultaneously to all players in a multiplayer game

Tags: flutter, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am building a simple multiplayer game in flutter which supports until 4 players playing at the same time. At a specific step in the middle of the game , I would like to show rewarded videos to all players at the same time. Is it possible to do this ? I would not like the scenario where one player may not get the add, since that would mean he would just stay there idle , waiting for others.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds possible, but your question is too broad. Try to split your problem into smaller pieces, provide some code example or algorithm with a description on what is working and what is not. And good luck with your game development.

Comment: It was more of a design problem due to the fact that you should request for a video reward to load , but sometimes there may be no ads available. But i guess I can always use my server to validate if all my clients loaded the ad , and only then I can show it to them. I don't know why I didn't think of it before . Thanks for your response .